# How to make a windows program for writing files to a cd using c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I want to develop an application for Windows for reading and writing CD. Please recommend any windows library, APIs, header files, source codes in C++.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my (C#) library at [scsi.codeplex.com](http://scsi.codeplex.com/). It shouldn't be hard to understand if you know C++.